# Generate Web Service Client from from Multiple WSDL in Java?

Tags: java, jax-ws, webservices-client, jax-ws-customization

I have to plan to generate WS-Client that have ability to detect running services then consume it from  multiple remote machine based on specified IP address/port. is it possible ?

As far I know, we can generate WS-Client from single WSDL only.

thanks in advance

Comment: You're looking in the wrong direction. You don't have to actually generate individual stubs, you could dynamically invoke webservices based on wsdl arguments. This will likely leave you with having to manipulate the SOAP payload manually, but it beats having to wrangle individual stubs

Comment: Did you mean [failover](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Failover) for the same webservice definition?